# Skylight bad idea on flat roof?

Tags: skylight

I have a metal roof with a 5 degree pitch in a temperate climate (snowed once in 50 years).  My living room equatorial facing Windows are largely blocked by my neighbors but I do get some sunlight coming thru clerestory Windows.

I'd like more sunlight and the roof itself receives unobstructed sunlight. I did talk to the solatube rep but he said they couldn't help me squeeze a tube between rafters etc.  And the light from those is pretty weak.

So I guess I'm looking at possibly a skylight or similar so I can get the sun in, with the aim of keeping alive some of my frost sensitive plants over winter.

But a structure in the middle of my roof is going to stop water draining unless I guess it gets diverted around the skylight without pooling.

Would it be a bad idea? Alternatives? And I'd rather not lose any heat in winter.

Comment: 5° grade should be enough to be able to route the water around the skylight.

Comment: And if not, put in a cricket.

Comment: I have a 2'x4' skylight in my kitchen roof which has a pitch just barely off flat (maybe 2 or 3 degrees). It's flashing is well sealed to the roofing material and it hasn't leaked in the 2+ years I've had the house - and central FL gets plenty of rain ...

Comment: I'm more concerned about water pooling, and rusting with a leak in a decade.

Answer (score 2):

Alternative: Fiber optic sky light. You don't need to put the solar panel on the roof- it can be set anywhere with good light (the side of the house and roof are commonly used though). The optic cables could be routed anywhere (like under the house, through the wall, etc.).

I'm not really making a recommendation, but [Huvco](http://www.huvco.com/) and [Wasco/Parans](http://www.wascoskylights.com/product/parans-fiber-optic-lighting/) came up first when I googled "fiber optic sky light".

Comment: I learn something new here every day. +1.

Comment: So a Swedish product from Parans sold by Wasco. Hard to find pricing though.